# Access old pytorch release from conda cloud

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

According to multiple sites, there was a binary release 0.2.1 for pytorch in repo peterjc123 (e.g. https://moodle.di.ens.fr/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=9#p33 ).
I also see a release 0.3.0 when looking at the only snapshot from archive.org.
However, the conda cloud website only shows the latest version (0.3.1; https://anaconda.org/peterjc123/pytorch/files ); the same applies to

```
conda search pytorch -c peterjc123
```

The old download links do not work anymore. 
How do I access the old version (I need a binary < 0.3 for windows 10; cuda80; py36)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the binaries uplodaed by user [Soumith](https://anaconda.org/soumith/pytorch/files), who is also the uploader for the (now stable branch) pytorch/pytorch on Anaconda cloud.

This channel has versions back to 0.2.1, so it should be satisfying your requirements.
If that does not work, also consider installing with regular `pip install` and specifying a version of your desire.

Edit: There might also be older versions for pytorch_cpu and other packages, I only checked for the "main" pytorch package.

Comment: Where can I get access to the 0.2.1 files? I only see win-64/pytorch-0.4.1-* files at the link.

Comment: Literally just scroll down the page, and you should be able to see them.

Comment: No, I can't find any. Are you refering to the osx/linux packages?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought those were the Windows packages as well, as they seemed to pop up a lot on top. :(

Comment: What really confuses me is that I expected a repository with versioning to also have a complete version history; but it is very sparse for Windows releases, only the most current version of pytorch in the respective channel (pytorch , anaconda, peterjc123, soumith, etc.) The linux/osx versions are all kept in the version history going back quite far.

Comment: Yeah, that is unfortunately the story for a lot of packages under Windows... Have you tried installing it with any of the alternatives mentioned [here](https://pytorch.org/previous-versions/)?

Comment: I don't understand that. Old releases for all other builds (linux/osx) can be found at official repos. I did not find any pytorch cu80 wheel for windows; conda packages appearently existed but have been removed; building yourself with cu80 spells is a lot of troubles...